# Send data that has nothing to do with button to modal using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, post, modal-dialog

I have this Ajax function:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.view_data2').click(function() {
                var employee_id2 = $(this).attr("id");

                $.ajax({
                    url: "includes/accomUser.inc.php",
                    method: "post",
                    data: {
                        employee_id2: employee_id2,
                        button_value: $(this).val() 
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#employee_detail2').html(data);
                        $('#adddata2').modal("show");
                    }
                });

                $('#addmodal2').modal("show");
            });
        });
```

It takes this button properties(value and id) and sends them to the modal via post:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary view_data2" id=" <?php echo $row['idFuncionarios']; ?>" value = "<?php echo $row['dia']; ?>" name = "envio">Ver</button>
```

Now, I need to take a data that has nothing to do with the button ($row['nomeDepartamento'];):

```
<td><?php echo $row['nomeDepartamento']; ?></td>
```

and send it via the same ajax function to the modal.

How would I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Where from? Is that data available on the page or in the script called by the ajax action?

Comment: Are you want to send to send `$row['nomeDepartamento'];` in ajax?

Comment: Yes, i want to send it in the same ajax function that is in the post

Comment: It is avaiable in the page

Comment: Let me clear you have a php veriable named `$row['nomeDepartamento'];` and you want to send this veriable to `Ajax` `data: {}` and after sending this you want to show that veriable inside of `modal`..

Comment: Yes! That's it! But the value is not in the button, it is somewhere in the page.

Comment: If it is already present in the page, why would you want to send it through ajax? Why isn't it automatically included in the modal content on page load?

Comment: I have a table. Each row in the the table has a button, that opens a modal respective to each user id. Each row has a ```$row['nomeDepartamento'];```. I don't think i get what you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your button will look like

```
<button data-field-name="<?php echo $row['nomeDepartamento']; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary view_data2" id="<?php echo $row['idFuncionarios']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['dia']; ?>" name="envio">Ver</button>
```

and retrive the `$row['nomeDepartamento'];` & after click funciton declare variable

```
var nomeDepartamento = $(this).attr("data-field-name");
```

and send this in `data:{}` and after success change html of any element like `$("element").html(nomeDepartamento)`
and there you go.

Comment: Just one more question. If a want to send more values, similar to that? How would I send them?  ```data-field-name``` again?

Comment: Made it. Just used ```data-field-name2``` and it worked. Thank you, the IRF!

Comment: `data-field-name` its just for example you can use any other like `data-anyname`